# Does it make sense to talk about unit in a ring that does not contain 1?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Does it make sense to talk about unit in a ring that does not contain 1?

I am intending to prove that if $r$ is irreducible and $r \nmid d$, then gcd(r, d) = 1.

The definition of irreducibility states that if r is irreducible then if we can express r = ab, then a is a unit or b is a unit. If I can assume that unit here is 1, then this is easy to solve as then the only non-"1" factor of r is r itself so if r does not divide d then gcd(r, d) is 1.

However, I am having trouble understanding and proving the case if the unit is not 1.

Comment: Where have you seen a definition of being irreducible in the context of non-unital rings?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft i have not but i am not sure thats why i am asking

Comment: Also, what you want to prove is no meaningful unless you assume the ring is a gcd domain (not sure if people ever define that concept for non-unutal rings, or if it can be made meaningful).

Comment: You have to have a $1$ if you are going to talk about units. Otherwise, units (multiplicatively invertible elements) wouldn't make sense. You can't have multiplicative inverses if you don't have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: can i assume unit to be 1? But it some cases unit might not necessarily be one right?

Comment: @manthanomen One could define a unit to be an element such that multiplication by that elements defined a bijective map. This agrees with the usual definition in the presence of a $1$.

Comment: Note the difference between "a unit" (meaning an invertible element) and "the unit" (meaning $1$).

Comment: yup, i mean here if r is reducible then r = ab where a is a unit or b is a unit. if i can't assume this unit to be 1, i can't see how i can arrive at the conclusion that gcd of r and b is 1. If i can, why?

Comment: As I already said, even the gcd part does not make sense without some further assumptions.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft so i have to assume it here for the statement to make sense? that the ring contains 1 factors of r are 1 and r?

Comment: No, you need to assume that the ring has a gcd (you probably also want to assume it to be an integral domain, and then it is called a gcd domain).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ok say if i assume the ring has a gcd and assume it to be an integral domain, it still doesn't solve my problem of not being able to conclude that gcd(r, b) = 1

Comment: Even in a gcd domain, the gcd is only defined up to a unit, so to prove it "equals" $1$, you just need to show that it is a unit.

Comment: Usually when proving that an element is irreducbile, It's very helpful to consider Norms in Euclidean Domains. $N(a) = 1  \leftrightarrow a$ is a unit
and  $N(ab) = N(a)N(b)$ .... etc

Comment: @alkabary No, the norm can also be $-1$ for a unit.

Comment: You can't prove that in general because the gcd need not exist. Divisibility theory (e.g. gcd domains) is normally done in rings with $1$. Why assume otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

In a non unital ring $R$, you can define $u\in R$ to be a left unit by $L_r:r\to R, r\mapsto ur$ being bijective (right unit and unit can be defined similarly).

Answer (score 0):

The notion of "irreducible" is defined for unital rings. Most authors assume all rings to be unital (and then use other names, for example [rng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_%28algebra%29), to denote non-necessarily unital rings).